# not sure what's going on in this code

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors, warnings

I have some C code, and I'm not quite sure what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM1 7
#define DIM2 5
#define RES_SIZE 1000

typedef double stackElementT;

typedef struct {
  stackElementT *contents;
  int maxSize;
  int top;
  int min2;
} stackT;

void StackInit(stackT *stackP, int maxSize) {
    stackElementT *newContents;
    newContents = (stackElementT *)malloc(sizeof(stackElementT)*maxSize);
    if (newContents == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    stackP->contents = newContents;
    stackP->maxSize = maxSize;
    stackP->top = -1;
}

void StackDestroy(stackT *stackP) {
    free(stackP->contents);
    stackP->contents = NULL;
    stackP->maxSize = 0;
    stackP->top = -1;
}

int StackIsEmpty(stackT *stackP) { return stackP->top < 0; }

int StackIsFull(stackT *stackP) { return stackP->top >= stackP->maxSize-1; }

void StackPush(stackT *stackP, stackElementT element) {
    if(StackIsFull(stackP)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't push element: stack is full.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    stackP->contents[++stackP->top] = element;
}

stackElementT StackPop(stackT *stackP) {
    if(StackIsEmpty(stackP)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't pop element: stack is empty.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return stackP->contents[stackP->top--];
}
int shell(char* s1, int arg) {
    printf(">   ");
    scanf("%s %d%*c", &s1, &arg);
    return arg;
}

int main() {
    char cmds[DIM1][DIM2] = {{"push"}, {"pop"}, {"add"}, {"ifeq"}, {"jump"}, {"print"}, {"dup"}};
    char* s1; int arg;
    arg = shell(s1, arg);
    printf("%s\n", &s1);
}
```

Input: `push 4`. It prints `J+` instead of "push" but prints `4` normally.

It also gives these warnings on compile:

```
stack.c: In function ‘shell’:
stack.c:60: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’
stack.c: In function ‘main’:
stack.c:71: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’
stack.c:65: warning: unused variable ‘cmds’
stack.c:69: warning: ‘arg’ is used uninitialized in this function
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: No. There's a small stack implementation above it, but I figured no one wanted to look through it.

Comment: Is there an intent to this code, or are you just asking what is the logic flow upon execution?  Because I don't see anything from the stack code being called in main(), just a scan and print...

Comment: Exactly. It's just that @jcomeau_ictx seemed to want all the code there. The stack implementation is irrelevant.

Comment: Why thank you for completely dismissing my code. If you don't want to help someone, then kindly leave the question.

Comment: @tekknolagi: I'd just like to say that it's nice you tried to do what was requested. Just try to remember for next time, it's better to have your compiler errors and warnings match the code example, so that the entire question is unified. On a side note, I personally like how this question follows up your last one. Hope the rest of the implementation goes well!

Comment: @tekknolagi, I didn't know it was your code. I got the impression you had found it somewhere and wanted to know what was wrong with it, and I didn't see enough right with it to bother with. it wasn't that I didn't want to help, it's that I didn't want to invest the time once I saw what a job it would be. but I wouldn't have been rude had I known it was your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `%s` format specifier, it expect a value which is a pointer to the start of a string. In C, this type is `char *`.

Taking your `main` function, your variable `s1` is of type `char *`. Therefore, `s1` is a valid parameter to `printf`, so this line is valid:

```
printf("%s\n", s1);
```

Note the *absence* of an `&` in front of `s1`. In your code, you used the `&`, which takes the address of `s1`, the result of which will be of type `char **`. This is the *wrong* type, so *don't* use the `&`.

The thing is, `printf` can't actually tell what type its arguments are, since it is a variadic function. It simply uses whatever arguments are there, according to the types specified in the format string.

The same thing goes for `scanf`, but there is a pitfall: you must make sure that enough memory is allocated to account for the user input, else you will experience a buffer overflow with unpredictable results. Aside from this, `printf` and `scanf` are perfectly complementary.

Anyhoo, this takes care of the compiler warnings, aside from the unused `cmds` variable (it's unnecessary in the provided code). Also, there is the part of `args` - it really should be a variable declared inside of `shell`, and not passed as a parameter, since its value is not even used inside `shell`.

Don't know what's up with the rest of the code. It's superfluous considering your `main` function only calls on `shell`.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. However, when I removed the ampersand (`&`), I get a segfault upon runtime, with the same input.

Comment: Like I mentioned, you must allocate a `char *` buffer *yourself*, i.e., declare `s1` to be something like `char *s1 = (char*)malloc(50);`. This gives you space for 50 characters of input. Alternatively, just use an array: `char s1[50];`. Either way, just remember that whenever you require input, you *must* make sure there is an adequate buffer for the input to be stored in.

Comment: That's because you have not initialized the pointer to point at reserved memory to store the text - in fact you have not even reserved such memory.

Comment: You can't just removed the &.  The problem is that s1 is uninitialized.  I think you're trying to make s1 point to the user input obtained from the call to scanf() in shell().  However, you haven't allocated any space to hold the user input.  Try making s1 an array instead of a pointer.  Also, you'll have to change shell() to accept a pointer to the array which would be a char**, not a char *.  The thing to remember is that in C, all parameters are passed by value.  When passing a pointer, the pointer value is copied but the value of the pointer in the caller is left unchanged.

Comment: @Sean: Responding to your last statement: yes, the pointer value is copied, but the data pointed to is not copied. The pointer parameter in the `shell` function and the pointer in the `main` function will point to the same memory, so any modification inside `shell` are visible from `main`. Therefore, changing `shell` to accept a `char **` argument is unnecessary, unless he plans to allocate the memory for the buffer inside of `shell`.

Comment: @Ken: Yes, of course, you are correct.  I guess I shouldn't try to answer questions on SO when it's late.

Comment: @Sean: I have the same problem in the mornings, before I've had a chance for coffee.